# How to structure a Scala mixin trait to cast a return to an extended type?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, mixins

I want to mixin a trait so that I can use a method from to return my own trait type. For example,

```
> trait M { 
    trait foo {def blah = "foo" }
    def name:foo = { new foo { override def blah = "name"}}}
> trait N extends M { 
    trait bar extends foo {}
    override def name:bar = super.name.asInstanceOf[bar]}
> object t extends N { val baz = name }
> t.name
  java.lang.ClassCastException: M$$anon$1 cannot be cast to N$bar
at N$class.name(<console>:7)
at t$.name(<console>:8)
at t$.<init>(<console>:8)
at t$.<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:10)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Interpreter.scala:988)
at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$l...
```

I know that I'm thinking about this in too much an OO fashion by using the `asInstanceOf`, and am ignorant in regards to something basic about the way traits work in Scala. How should I change N and its sub-types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M.name` constructs and returns a `foo`.  In `N.name` you call `super.name`.  Since `super.name` refers to `M.name`, `super.name` also constructs and returns a `foo`.  You then take that `foo` and call `.asInstanceOf[bar]`.  But this doesn't make sense since nothing in your code ever constructed a `bar`, and, while a `bar` is a `foo`, a `foo` is not necessarily a `bar`.

If you really want `N.name` to return a `bar`, then you need to override `M.name` so that you explicitly construct a `bar` and return it.

```
trait N extends M {
  trait bar extends foo {}
  override def name: bar ={
    val f: foo = super.name                // not what we want; it's not a `bar`
    new bar { override def blah = f.blah } // this is actually a `bar`
  }
}
```

Now we get:

```
scala> println(t.name.blah)
name
```